# Add databound function after kendogrid has been initialized

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Let's say I have initialized a kendogrid like this.

```
$('#' + grids[i].gridName).kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        width: 50, "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" />"
    },
    {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name"
    }]
}).css('width', '100%');
```

How can I add a databound function to the already existing kendoGrid?

The following does not work.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataBound = function(){
     //some code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBound", function(e) {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you may add databound function as below

```
$('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.bind('dataBound', function(e) { 
                 ...
});
```

Comment: You and vivek's methods both work. I'm accepting vivek's answer since he was a bit faster, and they're both equally as good. Thanks.